# add firstname and lastname in newsletter grid in magento 2.3.x

Tags: module, controllers, php-7, newsletter-subscriber, magento2.3.6

I want to add firstname and lastname in newsletter grid in Magento 2.3.x.

1. first_name and last_name in newsletter form in frontend.
2. adding columns to databse table "newsletter_subscribers".
3. display firstname and lastname column in newsletter grid in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the answer to your 1st question which is:: 'first_name and last_name in newsletter form in frontend.' this, as I am the new learner so there will be some mistakes in naming conventions and all hope you we never mind

The answer of:: first_name and last_name in newsletter form

1. you have to override the core phtml file of this form in your custom module inside::
   app/code/[Vendor]/[namespace]/view/frontend/templates/[filename].phtml
   add firstname and lastname code in overridden file ::
   [![phtml code is in bellow png link][1]][1]
2. also add 'default.xml' file inside ::
   app/code/[Vendor]/[namespace]/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
   add code as bellow in XML file
   `<referenceContainer name="footer"> <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe"  name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-"  template="[Vendor]_[namespace]::[filename].phtml"  ifconfig="newsletter/general/active"/> </referenceContainer>`

--->>>if this works for you please mark answer, if you can that would be helpful for me, thank you :)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQgrJ.png

Comment: Okay it's right code but i want to all 3 options as answers and also want data shown in newsletter grid in columns too. Thank you-@Ekta Rathod

Comment: okay ! if I found I'll sure upload it here!